# React-native-video not showing the video player

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-video

I am using react-native-video package to get video player in which i can play my youtube videos.

I tried this but only a empty space was coming instead of a video player.

```
import Video from 'react-native-video';
    <Video source={{uri: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gh2FaDqZp2g'}}
                       ref={(ref) => {
                         this.player = ref
                       }}
                     onBuffer={this.onBuffer}
                     onEnd={this.onEnd}
                     onError={this.videoError}
                     style={styles.backgroundVideo} />
```

style:

```
backgroundVideo: {
    height:300,
    width:'100%',
  }
```

Answer (score 8):

I think **Video** tag will accept Uri ending with .mp4 format..

Please replace your uri with this http://d23dyxeqlo5psv.cloudfront.net/big_buck_bunny.mp4

(**Note:** Some other uri can also be used with same format) and checkout.

But for streaming Youtube videos you will have to use **react-native-youtube** and **Youtube API Component**.

[Please refer this link for further](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-youtube)

Comment: Follow the "usage" example in the given link https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-video.. Follow the steps If it's not working post your error

Comment: The thing is that it is showing up no error just a blank space is coming due to that css

Comment: So anything came up? @Sandy

Comment: @Eshant Bist Sorry I try to send you some solutions within EOD

Answer (score 2):

I see there some problems in your code:

1/ uri: please replace by this link: "http://d23dyxeqlo5psv.cloudfront.net/big_buck_bunny.mp4"

```
source={{uri: 'http://d23dyxeqlo5psv.cloudfront.net/big_buck_bunny.mp4'}}
```

2/ Your style: as I remember `width: '100%` does not work, you should set it to a specific number. Or you can make video container view wraps the video view

```
<View style={styles.videoContainer}>
    <Video
        source={{uri: 'http://d23dyxeqlo5psv.cloudfront.net/big_buck_bunny.mp4'}}
        ref={(ref) => {
            this._player = ref
        }}                                      
        ...
        style={styles.video}/>
</View>
```

View style:

```
videoContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
},
video: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
},
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: The question is about playing an Youtube video. By default it would play the MP4 format.

Answer (score 1):

**Video is not showing because of these conditions required by IOS and react-native**

1. **URL passed on uri must be "HTTPS" to run on ios because by    default these are configured to https**

To run HTTP Video file you need to make these changes on info.plist file as mentioned on below image from doc of the package

[image]

So add the following snippet in the ios/Project-Name/info.plist file under dict XML, This way you will opt out the App Transport Security by apple.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```

It is not recommended to opt out of App Transport Security since Apple plans to require App Transport Security starting 1 January 2017, But if you want you can

For more information refer to this article

https://cocoacasts.com/how-to-add-app-transport-security-exception-domains

2. **If loading from local file system of project use require('path')
   directly on source prop. Ex -**

> source={require('../../assets/videos/test_video.mp4')}

Hope this will help you or somebody else.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it's very clearly mentioned in library that you have to use `.mp4` file, in my case .mp4 file url was also not working for android 10 and 11 so i have tried below solution and it worked for me.

still you can try this solution as it works for me try to change your `react-native.config.js` file with the following code

hope this will work for you

```
module.exports = {
  dependencies: {
    'react-native-video': {
      platforms: {
        android: {
          sourceDir: '../node_modules/react-native-video/android-exoplayer',
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

We tried Live streaming url in react native player.Audio was working but video was not showing.
Here is my Code

```
    <Video
      ref={videoRef}
      source={{ uri: 'https://www.cbsnews.com/common/video/cbsn_header_prod.m3u8'}}
      style={styles.video}
      controls={true}
      resizeMode="cover"
      autoplay={true}
      paused={!isPlaying} // Use the paused prop to control play/pause state
      onEnd={() => setIsPlaying(false)}
    />
```